# Last WHEN expression overrides result of first WHEN expression in CASE WHEN in SQL SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server, case

This looks so familiar to most of in this community as it is all about `SQL CASE` expression. But I am going now in triage mode rather doing actual implementation. I appreciate if there is optimal way to work around this.

**SCENARIO:**

I have one select statement where in I retrieve multiple columns from a table. The table has columns mostly with `numeric(10, 3)` datatype. I chose this datatype as I thought if I need to display `int` value the conversion would be easier rather vice versa. Here is the table structure.

Name: `FleetRange`

Columns:

```
CaptionID INT NOT NULL 
Caption   NVARCHAR(50) 
FleetRange_1      numeric(10,3)
FleetRange_2_4    numeric(10,3)
.......
Total     numeric(10,3)
```

Critera:

Current result:

[image: current query result]

My SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    CaptionId, Caption, 
    CASE 
       WHEN CaptionId IN (1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 14, 15, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23) 
          THEN CONVERT(INT, FleetRange_1)
       WHEN CaptionId IN (11, 12, 13) 
          THEN CONVERT(NUMERIC(10, 2), FleetRange_1)
       WHEN CaptionId IN (3, 10, 16, 19) 
          THEN CONVERT(NUMERIC(10, 3), FleetRange_1)
    END AS 'FleetRange_1'
FROM 
    FleetRange
```

**NOTE:**

What currently happening is, the last `WHEN` is overriding previous evaluation and hence every row display values with 3 `decimal` places even if there is an integer value.

I have applied same case structure for other `numeric(10,3)`, hence I have shortened the query.

instead of `case` written within above query, I tried below syntax too - but no difference.

```
WHEN 
   CaptionId = 11 OR 
   CaptionId = 12 OR 
   CaptionId = 13 
  THEN...
```

My **expectation** (desired actual result): my objective is - particular row value should be converted to int `numeric` given precision if the particular `when` expression with specific `CaptionID` is evaluated.

Something like below:

```
CaptionID  | Caption         | FleetRange_1 | FleetRange_2_4 | .....
        1  | SafetyFirst     |            0 |              1 |
       11  | DriveSafe       |         2.15 |            null|
        3  | Caution         |        1.025 |           2.174|
```

Comment: you can't have multiple data types in a single column in SQL

Answer (score 1):

Every expression in a query has a *single* data type.  The data type of a CASE expression is:

> the highest precedence type from the set of types in
>   result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression.

[CASE (TSQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

And see [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

If you want different display formatting for different rows in a single resultset, you'll have to convert them to strings and [Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) them yourself.